# Copy elision in initializer list?

Tags: c++, move-constructor, copy-elision

Consider this class

```
class A {
public:
    tracker tra;
    A(tracker _t) : tra(_t) {}
};
```

And call it through

```
A a {tracker()};
```

The object created by `tracker()` is never used until being stored in `a.tra`

Why don't the compiler optimize all the copy constructions away?

.

The tracker is defined here:

```
class tracker {
public:
    void mark(const char* v) {
        std::cout << v << ' ' << this << std::endl;
    }

    tracker() {
        mark("con");
    }

    tracker(const tracker& o) {
        mark("cpy");
    }

    tracker(tracker&& o) {
        mark("mov");
    }

    ~tracker() {
        mark("des");
    }

    tracker& operator=(const tracker&) {
        mark("=cp");
        return *this;
    }

    tracker& operator=(tracker&&) {
        mark("=mv");
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: It isn't allowed because `_t` is an lvalue

Comment: @HolyBlackCat are you sure nrvo applies in the constructor initializer list? I was under the impression it doesn't. I could be wrong.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat when running it prints "cpy"

Comment: You should add your compiler, the compile flags as well as the output

Comment: It's a copy because you don't move it. `A(tracker _t) : tra(std::move(_t)) {}` - eliding copies/moves by returning or initilize other objects from function arguments is not allowed afaik

Comment: I don't think the **guaranteed copy elision** feature kicks in with `_t`.

Comment: @bolov I could've said it better. I know it's not allowed now, but I think nothing prevents it from being viable in theory.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat right. I agree, it should be added in the standard

Comment: @TedLyngmo You're right, but that would still call its move constructor. The OP seems asking about *"in-place"* constructing.

Comment: @DeanSeo Yes but in that case the object to be created should be given the arguments needed to construct the object, not an already created instance. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/E37d7qTP6)

Comment: @TedLyngmo Nice solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler can't optimize out the copy construction of `tracker` in this case because the copy constructor and the destructor of `tracker` has observable side-effects. If the compiler optimizes out the copy construction ignoring that, it will change the observable behavior of the program thus violating the [as-if rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if).

There are exception to the as-if rule that allows the compiler to optimize out the copy/move construction even if the copy/move constructor and/or the destructor have observable side-effects. ([copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision))

But that exception rule is only applicable in some cases, and your code is not one of those. You are (copy-)constructing the member variable `tra` with the lvalue of type `tracker`. This is not the case that's mentioned in the copy elision rule.